# Adding Additional Customer Information to Cloud Function to Create Stripe Customer

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to add additional information to my cloud function so that way my Stripe customer has all of the data saved in the Firebase Database. However, my question is how can I implement the constants in my cloud function correctly so the information uploads correctly? Without the fullname, username, and profileImage in my cloud function and my registration function in the functions section, it creates the Stripe customer. How do I structure the constants for those three fields so they can upload as well? Or should I create an email and password registration screen, so I can create the stripeID, then create another screen for additional information to add to the reference? Thank you!

**Cloud Function:**

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const email = data.email
    const uid = context.auth.uid
    const fullname = context.auth.uid.fullname
    const username = context.auth.uid.username
    const profileImage = context.auth.uid.profileImage
  
    if (uid === null) {
      console.log('Illegal access attempt due to unauthenticated attempt.')
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Illegal access attempt')
    }
  
    return stripe.customers.create({
       email : email,
       fullname : fullname,
       username : username,
       profileImage : profileImage
    }).then( customer => {
      return customer["id"]
    }).then( customerId => {
      admin.database().ref("customers").child(uid).set(
        {
          stripeId: customerId,
          email: email,
          fullname: fullname,
          username: username,
          profileImage: profileImage,
          id: uid
        }
      )
    }).catch( err => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Unable to create Stripe customer.')
    })
  
})
```

**AuthService Function:**

```
static func createCustomer(credentials: CustomerCredentials, completion: @escaping(DatabaseCompletion)) {
        
        guard let imageData = credentials.profileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3) else { return }
        let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
        let storageRef = STORAGE_REF.reference(withPath: "/customer_profile_images/\(filename)")
        
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (meta, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: credentials.email, password: credentials.password) { (result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let uid = result?.user.uid else { return }
                    
                    let values = ["email" : credentials.email,
                                  "fullname" : credentials.fullname,
                                  "username" : credentials.username,
                                  "uid" : uid,
                                  "profileImageUrl" : profileImageUrl] as [String : Any]
                    
                    CustomerDataService.saveCustomerData(uid: uid, fullname: credentials.fullname, email: credentials.email,
                                                         username: credentials.username, profileImagUrl: profileImageUrl)
                    REF_CUSTOMERS.child(uid).setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: completion)
                }
            }
        }
        
}
```

**Registration Function:**

```
@objc func handleCreateAccount() {
        
        guard let profileImage = profileImage else {
            self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Please select a profile image.")
            return
        }
        
        guard let email = emailTextField.text?.lowercased() , email.isNotEmpty ,
            let fullname = fullnameTextField.text , fullname.isNotEmpty ,
            let username = usernameTextField.text?.lowercased() , username.isNotEmpty ,
            let password = passwordTextField.text , password.isNotEmpty ,
            let confirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text , confirmPassword.isNotEmpty else {
                self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Please fill out all fields.")
                return
        }
        
        if password != confirmPassword {
            self.simpleAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Passwords don't match, please try again.")
            return
        }
        
        showLoader(true, withText: "Registering Account")
        
        let credentials = CustomerCredentials(email: email, fullname: fullname, username: username,
                                              password: password, profileImage: profileImage)
        
        AuthService.createCustomer(credentials: credentials) { (error, ref) in
            if let error = error {
                Auth.auth().handleFireAuthError(error: error, vc: self)
                self.showLoader(false)
                return
            }
            
            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createStripeCustomer").call(["email": credentials.email,
                                                                              "fullname": credentials.fullname,
                                                                              "username": credentials.username,
                                                                              "profileImage": credentials.profileImage]) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    Auth.auth().handleFireAuthError(error: error, vc: self)
                    self.showLoader(false)
                    return
                }
            }
            
            self.showLoader(false)
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }
            guard let tab = window.rootViewController as? MainTabController else { return }
            tab.setupNavigationControllers()
            self.handleDismissal()
        }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete what I was trying to accomplish, I created a screen for customers to create an e-mail and password. This way the StripeID could be created, and then I created another screen to add the full name, username and profile image, and updated the database reference.